# Is there a construct like Java initializing blocks in C++?

Tags: java, c++

I read in some articles that there is something called Initializing blocks in java ; where we can perform some initializing assignments When the Class is loaded or an instance is created.

> Apart from methods and constructors, Initialization Blocks are the third place in a Java Program where operations can be performed.

```
class InitDemo
{
     static int y;
     int x;
 {
   y = 10;
   x =  0;
 }
}
```

I am asking if there is such paradigme in C++ ? 
Thank you.

Comment: C doesn't have the concept of classes being "loaded", and its view of statics is entirely different from Java's.  So, aside from static initializers there's nothing similar.

Comment: (In essence, the `static` block in Java is the class's constructor, because classes are (semi-)full-fledged objects.  C++ classes are not objects.)

Comment: (I should point out that your block above is not a `static` init block.  See my post below.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be pointed out that there are two different forms of initialization blocks in Java.  The bare `{...}` block, without the keyword `static`, is just a bit of compiler swizzling -- the text in the block is appended to the front of any constructors that are defined -- no separate code segment is generated.  A block that begins `static {...`, on the other hand, is a static initialization block and a (semi-)proper procedure in its own right (named, not surprisingly, "static").

The `static` block is executed only once, immediately (with a few caveats) after the class is loaded.  The non-static initializer is (by virtue of being copied into the constructors) executed every time a constructor is executed, and hence is generally inappropriate for static init.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, C++ does not have a direct equivalent for this Java construct.

To get similar behaviour, you would have to set `x` and `y` from `InitDemo`'s constructors (which you can also do in Java).

Comment: Yes indeed aix, i see that in contrast of java the constructors remain the only* place fo initilizing assignements for C++.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: Pretty much. In Java, a (non-`static`) initialization block is just a way to place some common code into every constructor.

Comment: Yes and beside that there is two flavors static intilizing blocks and non-static which i think  is helpfull.