# What's the C++ idiom equivalent to the Java static block?

Tags: java, c++, initialization, equivalent, static-block

I have a class with some static members, and I want to run some code to initialize them (suppose this code cannot be converted into a simple expression). In Java, I would just do

```
class MyClass {
    static int field1;
    static int field2;

    static {
        /* do some computation which sets field1 and field2 */
    }
}
```

Unless I'm mistaken, C++ does not allow for such static code blocks, right? What should I be doing instead?

I would like solution for both of the following options:

1. Initialization happens when process loads (or when the DLL with this class is loaded).
2. Initialization happens when the class is first instantiated.

For the second option, I was thinking of:

```
class StaticInitialized {
    static bool staticsInitialized = false;

    virtual void initializeStatics();

    StaticInitialized() {
        if (!staticsInitialized) {
            initializeStatics();
            staticsInitialized = true;
        }
    }
};

class MyClass : private StaticInitialized {
    static int field1;
    static int field2;

    void initializeStatics() {
        /* computation which sets field1, field2 */
    }
};
```

but that's not possible, since C++ (at the moment?) does not allow initialization of non-const static members. But, at least that reduces the problem of a static block to that of static initialization by expression...

Comment: (Can I just point out the mutable statics in Java are really not recommended.)

Comment: Non-static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520342/initializing-blocks-c-java

Comment: Should the `static block` be separate for each class? Or does a single one suffice? Why not create an initializing function and call it in `main`?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar: There are no classes involved here - just a block of code that runs once before `main()`. "Why not... call it in `main()`"? So that main doesn't have to know about it of course.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that there is no need for multiple static blocks? Still, no offense, but it seems like a bit of a hassle for a small problem, IMO.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar: No, that's not right. The whole point is that there isn't a single global point at which you know everything that needs to be run statically, but rather, every translation unit or file can add  such code, independently of the rest of the program.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### You can have static blocks in C++ as well - outside classes.

It turns out we can implement a Java-style static block, albeit outside of a class rather than inside it, i.e. at translation unit scope. The implementation is a bit ugly under the hood, but when used it's quite elegant!

#### Downloadable version

There's now a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/eyalroz/cpp-static-block) for the solution, containing a single header file: [`static_block.hpp`](https://github.com/eyalroz/cpp-static-block/blob/master/static_block.hpp).

#### Usage

If you write:

```
static_block {
    std::cout << "Hello static block world!\n";
}
```

this code will run before your `main()`. And you can initialize static variables or do whatever else you like. So you can place such a block in your class' `.cpp` implementation file.

**Notes:**

- You *must* surround your static block code with curly braces.
- The relative order of execution of static code is [not guaranteed in C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

#### Implementation

The static block implementation involves a dummy variable initialized statically with a function. Your static block is actually the body of that function. To ensure we don't collide with some other dummy variable (e.g. from another static block - or anywhere else), we need a bit of macro machinery.

```
#define CONCATENATE(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define EXPAND_THEN_CONCATENATE(s1, s2) CONCATENATE(s1, s2)
#ifdef __COUNTER__
#define UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER(prefix) EXPAND_THEN_CONCATENATE(prefix, __COUNTER__)
#else
#define UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER(prefix) EXPAND_THEN_CONCATENATE(prefix, __LINE__)
#endif // __COUNTER__
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _UNUSED
#else
#define _UNUSED __attribute((unused))
#endif // _MSC_VER
```

and here is the macro work to put things together:

```
#define static_block STATIC_BLOCK_IMPL1(UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER(_static_block_))

#define STATIC_BLOCK_IMPL1(prefix) \
    STATIC_BLOCK_IMPL2(CONCATENATE(prefix,_fn),CONCATENATE(prefix,_var))

#define STATIC_BLOCK_IMPL2(function_name,var_name) \
static void function_name(); \
static int var_name _UNUSED = (function_name(), 0) ; \
static void function_name()
```

**Notes:**

- Some compilers do not support `__COUNTER__` - it's not part of the C++ standard; in those cases the code above uses `__LINE__`, which works too. GCC and Clang do support `__COUNTER__`.
- This is C++98; you don't need any C++11/14/17 constructs. However, it's *not* valid C, despite not using any classes or methods.
- The `__attribute ((unused))` might be dropped, or replaced with `[[unused]]` if you have a C++11 compiler which doesn't like the GCC-style unused extension.
- This does not avert or help with the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order), since while you know your static block will execute before `main()`, you are not guaranteed when exactly that happens relative to other static initializations.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1020d498ce9c0209)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me a great deal.

Comment: @Amir: The please also consider starring the GitHub repository :-P

Comment: Minor note: I tested this on Android using Qt C++, and I didn't see a cout result on the console, but I was able to determine the block fired off by manipulating a static value then later spitting it out within normal app execution.

Comment: Regarding `__attribute((unused))`, for Visual Studio support, I but that in a `#define _UNUSED` and made that empty `#ifdef _MSC_VER`.

Comment: @BuvinJ: Yes, that should work - you are welcome to edit my answer and do that (but please make sure your change compiles correctly).

Answer (score 12):

For #1, if you really need to initialise when the process starts/library is loaded, you'll have to use something platform-specific (such as DllMain on Windows).

However, if it's enough for you to run the initialisation before any code from the same .cpp file as the statics is executed, the following should work:

```
// Header:
class MyClass
{
  static int myDatum;

  static int initDatum();
};
```

```
// .cpp file:
int MyClass::myDatum = MyClass::initDatum();
```

This way, `initDatum()` is guaranteed to be called before any code from that `.cpp` file is executed.

If you don't want to pollute the class definition, you can also use a [Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/1593077) (C++11):

```
// Header:
class MyClass
{
  static int myDatum;
};
```

```
// .cpp file:
int MyClass::myDatum = []() -> int { /*any code here*/ return /*something*/; }();
```

Don't forget the last pair of parentheses - that actually calls the lambda.

---

As for #2, there's one problem: you can't call a virtual function in the constructor. You're better off doing this by hand in the class instead of using a base class for it:

```
class MyClass
{
  static int myDatum;

  MyClass() {
    static bool onlyOnce = []() -> bool {
      MyClass::myDatum = /*whatever*/;
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

Assuming the class only has one constructor, that will work just fine; it is thread-safe, as C++11 guarantees such safety for initializing static local variables.

Comment: Your `static bool onlyOnce` is not thread-safe, I believe. It might executed more than once.

Comment: @einpoklum In C++11, function-scope statics are guaranteed to be initialised in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: @Angew: Will the above also be safe if myDatum is static const int ? Could this idiom be used to init a static const efficiently (and without external linker issues if I moved the constructor into the .cpp) before main() is run?

Comment: @ThomasKejser If it's `const`, you cannot use option #2 at all, `const` variables have to be initialised in their definition.

Comment: Your answer to #1 did not work for me in the scenario of having a class definition in a separate static library. The only thing that worked was declaring the static 'myDatum' equivalent in the library's namespace ("~global") scope. With that, I had to use a static bool to check if it's been initialized already, like you do for #2. I tested with -O3, this worked.

Comment: Moreover, I discovered that this (namespace-scope) solution above only works when the header where 'myDatum' is defined and initialized is (perhaps through some other headers) included in the non-library code that's using the library. So you have to make sure every class that relies on this static initialization block actually includes 'MyClass.h' in the header.

Answer (score 9):

You *can* initialize static data members in C++:

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar make_a_bar();

struct Foo
{
    static Bar bar;
};

Bar Foo::bar = make_a_bar();
```

You may have to think about inter-translation-unit dependencies, but that's the general approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice way to mimic a `static` block using C++11:

### Macro

```
#define CONCATE_(X,Y) X##Y
#define CONCATE(X,Y) CONCATE_(X,Y)
#define UNIQUE(NAME) CONCATE(NAME, __LINE__)

struct Static_ 
{
  template<typename T> Static_ (T only_once) { only_once(); }
  ~Static_ () {}  // to counter "warning: unused variable"
};
// `UNIQUE` macro required if we expect multiple `static` blocks in function
#define STATIC static Static_ UNIQUE(block) = [&]() -> void
```

### Usage

```
void foo ()
{
  std::cout << "foo()\n";
  STATIC
  {
    std::cout << "Executes only once\n";
  };  
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/6sjRzz).

Comment: This is inside a function, which doesn't count. Actually, there's a nifty solution which doesn't use any C++11, see my answer.

Comment: @einpoklum, just saw your answer & since you are using in production, it must be working well for you. However, the solution I wrote above works well outside the function as well (Demo edited). Yes, it does use C++11 to make resemble as close as Java's "static" block. We can do it with simple function as well, but then it will not have capabilities of capturing all. For example, `void foo () { static X x; }`. Suppose if you want to set some fields of `x` just once using `static` block then you must have a C++11 lambda. It won't be possible without it.

Comment: I don't quite understand your latter example. My static block is not intended (in Java) to hold global data, just to run something once at startup. Anyway, +1 for this solution generally.

Comment: **Warning** this solution is dangerous. It is luringly easy to use. You may use it to plant a static field into a class. The compiler is free to *optimise that away any time*, if he can prove there is no access.

Comment: Haven't faced any problem so far @Ichthyo. Moreover, lazy initialization is part of C++ and I haven't heard of compilers optimising it. What made you feel the above solution as dangerous.

Comment: two things are potentially dangerous. The compiler is free to optimise statics away entirely. It depends on fine points and circumstances if he does. And, second, it is tempting to do side-effects which involve statics / globals from other translation units. The fact such code often seem to work does not say anything.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 , u can have the following:-

static.hpp :-

```
#define M_CON(A, B) M_CON_(A, B)
#define M_CON_(A, B) A##B

#define STATIC_BLOCK \
        [[maybe_unused]] static const auto M_CON(_static_block,__LINE__) = []()
```

main.cpp:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include "static.hpp"

STATIC_BLOCK {
   std::cout << "my static block" << '\n';
   int A,B,C,D = 12;
   std::cout << "my static block with " << A << '\n';    
   return 0; // this return is must
}();

int main(){
    std::cout << "in main function\n";
}
```

This also works in C++11 without `[[maybe_unused]]`

Comment: Other than the "maybe unused", isn't this C++11?

Comment: @einpoklum yes but its gives warning without maybe_unused

Comment: You might think that it does, but actually, it [seems not to](https://godbolt.org/z/hExmYw).

Answer (score 1):

### In C++ there is no such idiom.

The reason lies in the entirely different nature of the code generated from C++: The runtime is not "managed". In the generated code, after compilation, there exists *no notion* of a "class" anymore, and there is no such thing like code entities loaded on demand by a "classloader".

There are some elements with roughly comparable behaviour, yet you really need to understand their nature precisely to exploit this behaviour.

- you can build your code into a shared library, which can be loaded dynamically, at runtime.
- in C++11, you can [std::call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) your initialisation from a class constructor. However, such code will run late, when the class instance is created, not when the executable or shared library is loaded
- you can define global variables and (class) static variables with an initialiser. This initialiser can be a function, which allows you to run code when the variable gets initialised. The execution order of these initialisers is well defined only within a single translation unit (e.g. one `*.cpp` file).

But you must not assume anything beyond that; esp. you can never be sure if and when this initialisation is actually performed. **This warning is for real**. Especially *do not assume anything about side-effects* of such initialisation code. It is perfectly legal for the compiler to replace such code by something deemed "equivalent" by the compiler. Future compiler versions can be assumed to become more and more clever in that respect. Your code may seem to work, but can break with different optimisation flags, different build process, newer compiler version.

---

**practical hint**: if you find yourself in the situation that you have several static variables, which you need to initialise properly, then chances are that you want to factor them out into a class. This class can then have a regular constructor and destructor to do the initialisation / clean-up. You may then place an instance of that helper class into a single (class) static variable. C++ gives very strong consistency guarantees for invoking ctors and dtors of classes, for anything which is accessible by official means (no casts, no low-level trickery).

Comment: Well, you can just forget about the class and the class loading, and just have the static block at TU scope, which is what I ended up doing. So - I think your answer is focusing on the wrong issue. I mean, I understand, yes, it will not be the same as running Java static blocks at dynamic class loading time, but like you said - we don't have that in C++.

Comment: @einpoklum I am aware of that. However, I have seen lots of java devs being trapped by unsing Java idioms in C++. For that reason, I think it should be made clear that there is no equivalent

Comment: The actual reason I needed this was to register some template instantiations in a factory at program load time.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off taking a different approach altogether. Does the collection of static information actually need to be defined inside StaticInitialized?

Consider creating a separate singleton class called SharedData. The first client that calls SharedData::Instance() will then trigger the creation of the collection of shared data, which will simply be normal class data, albeit living inside a single object instance that is allocated statically:

// SharedData.h

```
class SharedData
{
public:
    int m_Status;
    bool m_Active;

    static SharedData& instance();
private:
    SharedData();
}
```

// SharedData.cpp

```
SharedData::SharedData()
: m_Status( 0 ), m_Active( true )
{}

// static 
SharedData& SharedData::instance()
{
    static SharedData s_Instance;
    return s_Instance;
}
```

Any client interested in the shared collection of data would now have to access it via the SharedData singleton, and the first such client to call SharedData::instance() would trigger the setup of that data, in SharedData's ctor, which would only ever be called once.

Now your code suggests that different subclasses might have their own ways of initializing static data (through the polymorphic nature of initializeStatics()). But this seems a rather problematic idea. Are multiple derived classes really intended to share a single set of static data, yet each subclass would initialize it differently? This would simply mean that whichever class was constructed first would be the one to set up the static data in its own parochial way, and then every other class would have to use this setup. Is this really what you want?

I am also slightly confused as to why you would try to combine polymorphism with private inheritance. The number of cases where you would genuinely want to use private inheritance (as opposed to composition) is very small. I'm left wondering if you somehow believe that you need initializeStatics() to be virtual in order for the derived class to be able to call it. (This is not the case.) Yet you do seem to wish to override initializeStatics() in the derived class, for reasons that are not clear to me (see earlier). Something seems kooky about the whole setup.

Comment: The thing is that sometimes no "client" knows the API that's used in the static code. The static block might be registering something in another global structure which does act the way you suggested.