# Idiom for class with no members which only does anything on construction?

Tags: c++, idioms

I want a class which "has nothing" and you can't "do anything with it", but has something interesting happen when an instance of it is constructed. Now, sure, I can code that, e.g. something like

```
class MyIdiom final {
    MyIdiom() { /* magic goes here */ }

    /* maybe unnecessary? */
    MyIdiom(const MyIdiom&) = delete;
    operator=(const MyIdiom& other) = delete;
}
```

but I wonder if there isn't part of some commonly-used library, alongside other such "degenerate classes".

**Note**: Since people seem to be overly concerned with the use of such a class, suppose it's something like

```
template <typename F> class MyIdiom final {
    MyIdiom(F f) { f(); }
}

#define STATIC_BLOCK(_f) \
    auto MyIdiom<decltype(_f)> _myidiom_ # _f # _ # __LINE__ (_f);
```

Comment: Unless you're also going to do something in the destructor, can't you just use a normal function?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: `static MyIdiom foo;` for example.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Also, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that your object will only do something at construction and never be used for anything else, then you can pretty much just replace the whole class with a method (i.e. `void`) with the same parameters as the constructor. I'd call this the "unnecessary complication" idiom.

On the other hand I guess there may be some compile-time uses for it in situations like...

```
template<some things happening here>
MyIdiom() { }
```

so that the template magic takes place when that particular ctor is asked for. At the moment I can't think of anything other than setting flags when [hacking stateful TMP](http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/) to make this be useful.

Comment: About your first paragraph: You would be right if C++ had static blocks, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19227664/1593077).